App window resizing post launch (windows 10)
I have an issue where i want to launch an app/game which somehow, probably through registry forces a resolution. My problem is that i want to run an app, on a 2560x1440 monitor at a 2560x1080p (aka ultra wide). I know for a fact that the app supports this resolution natively but doesnt allow this kind of "sorcery" when the monitor itself isnt of that resolution.
Like sure i could make my monitor to go to that res, but then id have 2 black bars. I only want to resize the app window. Is this somehow possible? I tried using WinReform from GitHub but that app wont even recognize the process.
If i edit the registry values, the moment the app starts, it override those values. But theres propbably a small window/gap there  i could override them again before it actually launches. Or Would can you make like a script that runs i na loop, constantly overriding the registy values with mine?
thanks!
